# Set .htaccess rules to specify different folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to set a rule in .htaccess if I enter in the url www.mydomain.com/compare.php set 'public_html' as root otherwise anything come in the url set root as 'public' folder.

```
RewriteRule ^(?!compare-source.php).*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I want to achieve following result.

if url is **www.mydomain.com/compare.php** hit following file.

```
public_html/compare.php
```

if urls are **www.mydomain.com/** OR **www.mydomain.com/home** etc hit following file.

```
public_html/public/index.php
```

I am weak in regex and in these apache rules always :-( can someone give me the solution with good description?

Your answers are welcome, please can you describe how this crazy things work in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^((?!compare\.php).*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

The [RewriteEngine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) directive enables or disables the runtime rewriting engine.

The [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive defines a rule condition. The following Rule is only used if this condition is met; In our case, if REQUEST_URI (the path component of the requested URL) does not (because of `!`) begin (because of `^`) with `/public`. We need this condition because we don't want to rewrite already rewritten URL - that would cause loop and Internal error 500.

Finally, the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) will match regex *Pattern* (`^((?!compare\.php).*)$`) against part of the URL after the hostname and port, and without the leading slash. If the pattern is matched, the Substitution (`public/$1`) will replace the original URL-path.

In plain language, if URL path does not begin with `compare.php` (because of `?!`), pick everything (`.*`) between beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) and place it in variable `$1`. Then replace the original URL path with `/public/$1`.

@Anubhava's answer is also correct, he just placed both conditions in RewriteRule, and also it could be written even more readable as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/compare\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more explanation about what this does, in order to make this a more complete answer.

Comment: @Dusan Bajic your solution was perfect match, but if you can describe how it is working... Thanks

Comment: Sorry didn't see your answer- mine was pretty similar so I deleted it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this .htaccess in site root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# route /home/ or /home to /
RewriteRule ^home/?$ / [L,NC]

# if not compare-source.php or public/* then route to /public/*
RewriteRule ^(?!public/|compare-source\.php$).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```